# Javascript passing color into table name css

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is very close to working but I just can't seem to get the final bit right to apply the individual pathColor to the row with the same index.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Set row colour based on chart colours
  $(function() {
    var paths = $('#results_donut .highcharts-series path');
    var rows = $('.result-figures table tr');
    paths.each(function(idx, element){
      var path = $(this)
      var pathColor = path.attr('fill');
      rows.each(function(idx) {
        $(this).css('color', pathColor);
      })
    });
  });
```

This is outputting the last pathColor and applying it to every row. Does anyone know how to correctly apply the pathColor of each path to the corresponding row based on the index?

Comment: Maybe you want "background-color" instead of color? or what is the expected result?

Comment: Can you include a sample of the html structure, or similar structure which exhibits the behavior, that correlates to this code?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are changing all the rows for every path, so you end up with the color of the last path. You need to access the correct row based on the path index:

```
$(function() {
    var paths = $('#results_donut .highcharts-series path');
    var rows = $('.result-figures table tr');
    paths.each(function(idx, element){
      var path = $(this)
      var pathColor = path.attr('fill');
      rows.eq(idx).css('color', pathColor);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code:

```
rows.each(function(idx) {
    $(this).css('color', pathColor);
})
```

applies `pathColor` to all `rows` elements...

Where are colors stored?? If you create an array of colors you can assign a different one to each element inside `rows`:

```
var colorsArray = // get the colors;
rows.each(function(idx) {
    $(this).css('color', colorsArray[idx]);
})
```